# Unity3d and CityEngine

Tags: unity-game-engine, openstreetmap, fbx

I created a small city in CityEngine using the openstreetmap data (osm file), where I've the latitude, longitude and some others details of each node. Now I want to export this information to the Unity3d, so I exported the city as fbx file. At this point everything is going ok.

The problem is ... in cityEngine each block/shape represents a different object, however in unity3d this is not happen. The data is divided per texture (or something like that). But I need to recognize each block/shape or at least I need to know the right position of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a option in the exporter where you can export the scene as centered around the xyz origin (exporter options).
2. The exporter has many settings for mesh-granularity. The meshes are per default merged by material. But you can of course also export for each shape one object etc.

Please visit the CityEngine Forum for more info:

http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/45-Solutions

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/51437-Export-Mesh-and-Material-Granularity?highlight=cityengine+unity